# jquery get form id when a checkbox is clicked

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have the following javascript code that is working, but the var form = this.form.id is correct?

```
$("#Wnoreportyet").click( function() {
          var form = this.form.id

    $("#dialog-noreportyet").dialog({
      buttons : {
        "Ακύρωση" : function() {
            document.getElementById(form).Wnoreportyet.checked = 0; 
            $(this).dialog("close");
        },
        "ΟΚ" : function() {
            document.getElementById(form).submit(); 
            $(this).dialog("close");
        }
      }
    }); 
  });
```

I am not sure for this because in jsp (html) code I use more than one forms.

`<div id="subtabs-6">`
`<div id="draggable6" class="ui-state-highlight">`
`<h3 class="ui-widget-header">Έκθεση ελέγχου</h3>`

`<table width="100%" cellspacing="0">`

`<tr>`
`<form id="fileupload" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" action="upload.jsp"><input type="file" name="ImageFile" id="ImageFile" />`
`<td width="14%" align="left">Βήμα 1`
`</td>`
`<td colspan="2" align="left">`
`<button type="submit" name="button" id="button3"  onclick="return thissubmit('fileupload');">Ανέβασμα</button>`
`<input name="Wupdatekind" type="hidden" value="auditreport" /></td>`
`</form>`
`</tr>`

`<form id="formauditreport" method="post" action="appointofcaid_update_finish.jsp">`
`<tr>`
`<td rowspan="3" align="left">Βήμα 2    </td>`
`<td colspan="2" align="left"><input type="checkbox" name="Wnoreport" id="Wnoreport" />  Ολοκληρώθηκε χωρίς έκθεση</td>`
`</tr>`
`<tr>`
`<td width="25%" align="left">Ημ καταχώρισης</td>`
`<td width="61%" align="left">01/10/2015</td>`
`</tr>`
`<tr>`
`<td align="left">Ημ έκθεσης</td>`
`<td align="left"><input name="Wreportdate" type="text" id="Wreportdate" value=""></td>`
`</tr>`
`<tr>`
`<td colspan="3" align="center">Δεν ολοκληρώθηκε ο έλεγχος
          <input type="checkbox" name="Wnoreportyet" id="Wnoreportyet" 
                                              disabled="disabled"/>`
`</td>`
`</tr>`
`<tr>`
`<td colspan="3" align="center"><button type="submit" name="sbutton6"  id="sbutton6" value="Ενημέρωση">Ενημέρωση</button>`
`<input name="Wupdatekind" type="hidden" value="auditreport" /></td>`
`</tr>`

`</form>`
`</table>`

`</div>`

Comment: show html. i would do it like `var  form = $(this).closest('form').attr('id')` assuming that the button is inside the form

Comment: also for checkbox please use `change` event reserve `click` event for button.

Answer (score 3):

Asuming that checkbox is inside the form that you need to get id:

```
 $("#Wnoreportyet").click( function() {
      var form = $(this).parents('form').attr('id');
 }
```

More information:

https://api.jquery.com/parents/

Comment: Marcos Perez I take this error when I change from this.form.id: Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'Wnoreport' of null

Comment: Your problem is here: `document.getElementById(form).Wnoreportyet.checked = 0; `, it seems that doesn't find the form id. Please, make a jsfiddle.net reproducing the problem and I can help you better.

Comment: No after the var form = $(this).parents('form').attr('id') I add an an alert(form) and says undefined.

Comment: I have try and  `$(this).parents('form').attr('id')` but the alert says 'undefined'
only the  `var form = this.form.id` working fine.

Comment: Can you share your HTML structure? It's important to see the problem

Comment: Marcos Pérez Gude I have added to my first message.